# CloudFoundry - Application 'controlealunos' does not exist

Tags: cloud-foundry

I think that i'm suffering a bug problem. I created a application on Cloud Foundry with the name "controle**A**lunos" with the upper case letter A.

When i execute the command

```
cf-apps
```

i get this result:

```
+----------------+----+---------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| Application    | #  | Health  | URLs                            | Services      |
+----------------+----+---------+---------------------------------+---------------+
| controleAlunos | 1  | RUNNING | controlealunos.cloudfoundry.com | mysql-86d568b |
+----------------+----+---------+---------------------------------+---------------+
```

But when i try to update my project whit the command :

```
prod cf-update controleAlunos controleAlunos-0.1.war
```

i receive an error

```
Error Application 'controlealunos' does not exist.
```

I think that it should be the name of my application. I put it with one Upper Case letter controle**A**lunos and i'm receving the error with no upper case letter controlealunos.

I tried to rename it, but i still get the error.

Any Sugests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the project name you created is "controlealunos" which resulted in the app.name property in application.properties is a lower case name, while the name used to push onto CF is "controleAlunos". You can try change the value in the properties file and update again.